# windowed cross-correlation using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics, cross-correlation

I have two data series, that are slightly shifted to each other. Both contain nan values, that need to be respected. Hence I would like to align them automatically. My idea is to use cross-correlation and numpy arrays to solve the problem. The code below is extremely slow and I would like to speed things up, but as a non python expert, I don't see any possibilities for improvement.

The idea is to have a baseline and target array. The code calculates the offset of each target position relative to the baseline in a windowed fashion. For each window it is calculated how much the data point has to be shifted for an optimal alignment. The first point that can be aligned is at `window_size//2` and the last at `basline.size-window_size//2`

```
window_size = 50
N = 100
randN = 10

baseline = np.random.rand(N,)
target = np.random.rand(N,)

mask=np.zeros(N,dtype=bool)
mask[:randN] = True
np.random.shuffle(mask)
baseline[mask] = np.nan
np.random.shuffle(mask)
target[mask] = np.nan

stacked = np.column_stack((baseline,target))
stacked_windows = sliding_window_view(stacked, (window_size,2))

offset_np = np.zeros([stacked.shape[0], ])
offset_np[:] = np.nan

for idx in range(stacked_windows.shape[0]):
  window = stacked_windows[idx]
  baseline_window_np = window.reshape(window_size,2)[:,0]
  target_window_np = window.reshape(window_size,2)[:,1]
  #
  baseline_window_masked = ma.masked_invalid(baseline_window_np) 
  target_window_masked = ma.masked_invalid(target_window_np) 
  #
  cc_np = np.empty([window_size + 1, ], dtype=np.float32)
  cc_np = np.zeros([window_size, ])
  cc_np[:] = np.nan
  for lag in range(-int(window_size//2),int(window_size//2)):
    masked_tmp = ma.masked_invalid(shift_numpy(target_window_masked, lag))
    cc_np[lag+int(window_size//2)] = ma.corrcoef(baseline_window_masked,masked_tmp)[0,1]
  if not np.isnan(cc_np).all():
    offset_np[window_size//2+idx] = np.floor(window_size//2)-np.argmax(cc_np)
    
result_np = np.column_stack((stacked, offset_np))
result_df = df = pd.DataFrame(result_np, columns = ['baseline','target','offset'])
```

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look at fast convolution methods. Using the convolution theorem, crosscorrelation can be sped up

Comment: For any convolution operation i would recommend using ```np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided``` to get the windows. If you have the latest numpy version you could even use ```np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view```

Comment: @Kevin I'm using `sliding_window_view` already